# Dataframe one-to-many from each cell of a column to another's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A simple dataframe of 2 columns that I want to have the contents in each column to be merged (or list side by side) with each other. For example:

[image]

Seems there's a simple way but I couldn't recall and retrieve it. I tried 'explode' and 'melt', but they are not working.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ["David","Mike","Kate"], 
'info' : ["Department","Titile","Gender"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.explode('name')
print (df)
```

What further things can I try?

Comment: Does your result should like the left of the picture or should be like the right side of the picture?

Comment: @toRex, result on the right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a cross-join on two columns using [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by creating a `tmp` column:

```
In [429]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.name, columns=['name'])   
In [430]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['info'], columns=['info'])

In [433]: df1['tmp'] = 1
In [435]: df2['tmp'] = 1

In [438]: res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['tmp']).drop('tmp', 1)

In [439]: res
Out[439]: 
    name        info
0  David  Department
1  David      Titile
2  David      Gender
3   Mike  Department
4   Mike      Titile
5   Mike      Gender
6   Kate  Department
7   Kate      Titile
8   Kate      Gender
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [numpy repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) and [numpy tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to build your series and recombine using [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
name = pd.Series(np.repeat(df.name.array, len(df)), name="name")
info = pd.Series(np.tile(df["info"].array, len(df)), name="info")
result = pd.concat([name, info], axis="columns")
result


     name   info
0   David   Department
1   David   Title
2   David   Gender
3   Mike    Department
4   Mike    Title
5   Mike    Gender
6   Kate    Department
7   Kate    Title
8   Kate    Gender
```

Comment: thank you. hope you don't mind I choose another for the answer.

Comment: @MarkK, not at all. Cheers, mate.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two new lists that multiply the values by the total rows. One column should have the index sorted. Then, join the lists in a dataframe.

```
c1 = [*pd.concat([df['name']]*df.shape[0])]
c2 = [*pd.concat([df['info']]*df.shape[0]).sort_index()]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(c1,c2)), columns=['name', 'info']).sort_values('name').reset_index(drop=True)
df
Out[1]: 
    name        info
0  David  Department
1  David      Titile
2  David      Gender
3   Kate  Department
4   Kate      Titile
5   Kate      Gender
6   Mike  Department
7   Mike      Titile
8   Mike      Gender
```

Sammy gave me an idea to make above code slightly more concise:

```
c1 = pd.concat([df['name']]*df.shape[0], ignore_index=True)
c2 = pd.concat([df['info']]*df.shape[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([c1, c2], axis=1)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, it could be consider from list point of view, using baby programming language:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ["David","Mike","Kate"], 
'info' : ["Department","Titile","Gender"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

names = df['name'].tolist() 
all_info = df['info'].tolist()

for n in names:
    for a in all_info:
        print (n, a)
```

Output:

```
David Department
David Titile
David Gender
Mike Department
Mike Titile
Mike Gender
Kate Department
Kate Titile
Kate Gender
```